# Properties of varieties that can be lifted under etale morphisms

Tags: algebraic-geometry, abstract-algebra

Let $X$,$Y$ be varieties over some field $k$ of char $0$ (not necessarily algebraically closed). Suppose we have an etale morphism $f : Y \to X$.

**My question**: for what properties P can we say that if $X$ has P, then $Y$ has also P?

For example if $X$ is proper we can say that $Y$ is also proper. References/proofs are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously every property P of morphisms works which is stable under composition and contains all etale morphisms. For example "smooth".

Comment: what about P being the property of being geometrically integral? This is not a local property, so I don't think it lifts under the etale map. What other properties should we add to $f$ in order to make it an integral morphism?

Comment: Perhaps you should add this to your question and un-accept my answer (which is more or less just a comment).